# get start and end for each factor, when there are double occurences of a factor

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataframe where I want to get the start and end T of a variable. Here's a subset of my dataframe:

```
structure(list(compID = c("d0627-Cc010-27", "d0627-Cc010-27", 
"d0627-Cc010-27", "d0627-Cc010-27", "d0627-Cc010-27", "d0627-Cc010-27", 
"d0627-Cc010-27", "d0627-Cc010-27", "d0627-Cc010-27", "d0627-Cc010-27", 
"d0627-Cc010-27", "d0627-Cc010-27", "d0627-Cc010-27", "d0627-Cc010-27", 
"d0627-Cc010-27", "d0627-Cc010-27", "d0627-Cc010-27", "d0627-Cc010-27", 
"d0627-Cc010-27", "d0627-Cc010-27"), total_turn_angle = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, -6.45412963, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, -6.434909322, NA, NA, NA, NA), T = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 
43L, 44L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```

I have three variables here: compID is my unique ID (I have tons of IDs and this is just one ID), total_turn_angle is the factor that I want to know the start and end T. Since I only have one value for total_turn_angle, I used the midpoint of T to put the value in. So in this example: -6.454130
is the total_turn_angle from T 1:10 and -6.434909 is the total_turn_angle for T 35:44.

Now, I want to know the start and end of T for that total_turn angle. So for this example, the answer will be:

```
compID          total_turn_angle    start   end
d0627-Cc010-27  -6.454130           1       10
d0627-Cc010-27  -6.434909           35      44
```

Hope someone could help!
Thank you!

Edit: made the sample data frame smaller and edited the explanation.

Comment: Do you think you could illustrate this problem with 10 rows instead of 127? It would be clearer and easier that way.

Comment: More explanation would be nice too. I've looked at the full data--it's clear the 115 and 374 are the `T` values for the first an last row, but I have no idea why the `172` and `306` values are the other values you want in the result.

Comment: @GregorThomas I edited as you suggested. Hopefully, it's clearer now. Thanks

Comment: I appreciate the shorter example, but I'm still confused. Can you explain where `10` comes from in the answer? The non-NA T value is on row 6, so there are 5 values before it, so maybe `((row with non-NA T value) - 1) * 2 = 10`?? And then this example is perhaps too short because you talk about another T value `-6.434909` but that's not in your sample data...

Comment: @GregorThomas apologies for the mistake. Here it is! Thanks

Comment: Still no explanation. I still don't understand. Does it have to do with the `T` values? Consecutive runs of integers in `T`? Something else???? **Please explain where `10` comes from. Please explain where `35` comes from.**

Comment: @GregorThomas  In my explanation: So in this example: -6.454130 is the total_turn_angle from T 1:10 and -6.434909 is the total_turn_angle for T 35:44. So the start time for the former total_turn_angle is 1 and end time is 10. While for the latter is start is 35 and ends at 44. These 2 total_turn_angles are separated from each other due to the gap between their T. I don't know how to make it clearer than that.

Comment: Okay, so it's the consecutive integer values of T get grouped together. That's clear. We can look for any differences in T greater than 1. Thanks for mentioning the "gap".

Answer (score 1):

Calling your data `df`:

```
df %>%
  group_by(
    compID
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    grp = cumsum(c(1, diff(T)) != 1)
  ) %>%
  group_by(compID, grp) %>%
  summarize(
    total_turn_angle = first(na.omit(total_turn_angle)),
    start = min(T),
    end = max(T),
    .groups = "drop"
  ) %>%
  select(-grp)
# # A tibble: 2 × 4
#   compID         total_turn_angle start   end
#   <chr>                     <dbl> <int> <int>
# 1 d0627-Cc010-27            -6.45     1    10
# 2 d0627-Cc010-27            -6.43    35    44
```

Comment: Thanks! This works well when diff (T) = 1. For some of my other data, diff(T) is sometimes 2 or 3. How do I proceed in that case. Sorry, this information is missing from the question because I did not expect gaps >1 between T. Thanks

Comment: I mean, none of that information is the question. I had to ask 3 times in comments before you confirmed that the gaps are what matter. But you can easily adjust the threshold, where I have `!= 1` in the code you could use `> 3` instead to allow for gaps of size 1, 2, or 3 without creating a new group.